# Java annotation - method return type namespace

Tags: java, annotations, wsdl

I have property in my class defined like:

```
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="cellValues")
    @XmlElement(name="cellValue")
    protected ArrayList<String[]> getCellValues()
```

When I use javaToWs it generate new complexType for Arraylist what is fine with me, but I would like to set a namespace for it... because default NS is http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use @XmlRootElement annotation for specific namespace.

Check this [url](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html).

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong title it is not property but return type... so XmlRootElement is not working

Comment: And @XmlElement namespace attribute?

Comment: It set namespace for property but not for its type and because type is in library I can not to specify on it